# Changing the MaxRecievedMessageSize for a custom WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have following WCF service hosted in SharePoint:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPrintService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/Print", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
  string Print(PrintMessage message);
}
```

The service host definition looks like:

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
               Service="..."
               Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory, ..." %>
```

Everything looks right and works fine. I can post an AJAX message from the client with jQuery. But when the post data's size is huge I get bad request error (400). The `MaxReceivedMessageSize` for WCF has to be changed to a higher value I think.

I found this [blog](http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=121). So I opened PowerShell, got the web application, called the `WebService` property on it. Only `listdata.svc` service was listed in `WcfServiceSettings`.

I have created a new `SPWcfServiceSettings` object `$wss`, changed the size properties, and added it into the list: `$ws.WcfServiceSettings.Add('printservice.svc', $wss); $ws.Update()`.

The result is that I still get error 400.

What I am doing wrong? Is there a way to change that value on the fly? Maybe by inheriting from `MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory` and doing some extra work?

Comment: Problem has nothing to do with data size. Problem was building a JSON object with real world data. Real world data have quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

This blog post may help: http://www.sharepoint.bg/radi/post/Custom-WCF-Services-and-setting-Reader-Quotas-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

The following code will set all the quotas to their max value. If you are still getting errors with that quota then you are likely trying to send too much info in one call and its time to split it into multiples.

```
SPWebService contentService = SPWebService.ContentService;

contentService.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = -1;

SPWcfServiceSettings wcfServiceSettings = new SPWcfServiceSettings();
wcfServiceSettings.ReaderQuotasMaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
wcfServiceSettings.ReaderQuotasMaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
wcfServiceSettings.ReaderQuotasMaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;
wcfServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
wcfServiceSettings.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
wcfServiceSettings.ReaderQuotasMaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue;
wcfServiceSettings.ReaderQuotasMaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue;
wcfServiceSettings.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

contentService.WcfServiceSettings["MyService.svc"] = wcfServiceSettings;

contentService.Update(true);
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan. Further investigation has shown that the problem had nothing to do with data size. It was a problem stringifying JSON object which has quotation marks. Problem came out with real data testing.

Comment: Im glad you found a solution, can you please add it and mark it as the answer for anyone that may have a similar problem in the future

Comment: Dead link. WebArchive version : https://web.archive.org/web/20160121030402/http://www.sharepoint.bg/Radi/post/Custom-WCF-Services-and-setting-Reader-Quotas-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx